# Transforming polygon geometry across antimeridian in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, buffer

I am working on a Python script in QGIS 3 that creates buffers around points in Web Mercator ([EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857)) and transforms the buffers into WGS84 ([EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326)).

I have a problem with geometries that cross antimeridian (180 deg longitude) - after transformation the buffers (circles) show up as long rectangles that span from -180 to +180 longitude, with actual buffers (circles) being "excluded" from these geometries.

Fig. 1: Buffer in Web Mercator that crosses antimeridian

[image: Buffer crossing antimeridian]

Fig. 2: Buffer after transforming into WGS84

[image: Buffer after transforming into WGS84]

How best to transform geometries that span across antimeridian?

Is there a way to fix the output geometries?

Comment: If you want to use geometries that cross the antimeridian you need to use a projection that is not split by it, or split the geometry.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton for your suggestion. However, why it is possible to create and display a polygon (buffer) that crosses the antimeridian? I've tried both ways: from WGS84 to WebMercator and the other way round. I can create a buffer in both coordinate systems and they show correctly. The issue arises only when the geometry is transformed to another coordinate system.

Comment: I worked on a project where I had to create custom Coordinate Systems for global earthquake points. I ran into a very similar problem. My question doesn't deal with the problem directly but it may help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263379/custom-transverse-mercator-projection-with-fiona-and-shapely

Comment: Likely your “native” buffer in either coordinate system results in points outside the official bounds, eg longitudes > 180 or < 180. These display correctly on many maps. When you convert, the conversion probably normalizes the points to the official bounds, breaking the display.

Comment: @ziggy (and Ian Turton) - thanks, your suggestions to create a custom projection worked! For buffers that cross antimeridian I'm using a modified WGS84 with a primary meridien centered at 180 deg and then transforming back to the regular WGS84. The output geometry shows up correctly. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ziggy - feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered and give you credits.